# vb.net set multiple SQL values to the same row in one query

Tags: sql, vb.net, set, sql-update

i have the following code which will set 2 values in the same row, its really simple but i am not sure how to combine it in one query

```
 Dim cnn As New SqlConnection
            Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT catalogid, delivered,nodilivary FROM supporder", cnn)
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "update supporder SET delivered=@delivered WHERE catalogid=@catalogid"
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@delivered", GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "delivered")))
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@catalogid", GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "catalogid")))
            cnn.Open()
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cnn.Close()
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "update supporder SET nodilivary=@nodilivary WHERE catalogid=@catalogid"
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@nodilivary", GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "nodilivary")))
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@catalogid", GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "catalogid")))
            cnn.Open()
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cnn.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a comma to separate each field you are updating.

```
UPDATE supporder SET nodilivary=@nodilivary, delivered=@delivered WHERE catalogid=@catalogid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim cnn As New SqlConnection

Dim sql as String = string.Format("update supporder set delivered={0}, nodilivary={1} where catalogid={2}", _
                    GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "delivered")  _
                    GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "nodilivary") _
                    GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "catalogid") )           


Dim sqlcmd As New Sqlsql, cnn)
cnn.Open()
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear()
cnn.Close()
```

I don't have a VB close to hand  but this should be pretty close.

Edit:

this is a version of the above using Command Parameters which (thanks for the comments) a simplistic defence again SQL Injection and is safer than the above code:

```
Dim cnn As New SqlConnection

Dim sql as String = "update supporder set delivered=@delivered, nodilivary=@nodilivary where catalogid=@catalogid"

Dim sqlcmd As New Sql(sql, cnn)
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@delivered", GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "delivered"))
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@nodilivary", GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "nodilivary"))
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@catalogid", GridControl2.GetCellValue(currentrowindex, "catalogid"))
cnn.Open()
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear()
cnn.Close()
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a possible opening to sql injection?  Assuming text could be in those data grid cells?

Comment: @pilotcam yes it would. But I'm assuming that there would be more layers between the UI and commands. After doing some reading I can see that using parameters is a simple way to help against this. Corrected the answer - thanks!